# Removing row when a key is empty with postgres json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.4

Query

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
    select book_id, book_title,
    (
        select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
        from (
            select chapter_id, chapter_title, chapter_number
            from chapters
            where chapters.book_id = books.book_id
            ORDER BY chapter_number
        ) d
    ) as chapters
    from books
) t
```

Row (1)

```
{
   "book_id":"c77c049c-d096-472f-a690-b48a9e979d86",
   "book_title":"Ask the Dust",
   "chapters":null
}
```

Row (2)

```
{
   "book_id":"4a7cfa6d-573a-4fda-9258-8800fa217f4e",
   "book_title":"Before I Self Destruct",
   "chapters":[
      {
         "chapter_id":"8e2ac988-3d48-489d-a81a-745536da7164",
         "chapter_title":"Sunshine Cleaning",
         "chapter_number":1
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I remove the row completely when chapter comes out null?

I tried looking for chapters with **WHERE (books->'chapters') IS NOT NULL** but the error it throws is 
'books -> unknown'

Answer (score 0):

Your query allows books without chapter because of the scalar subquery technique that is used to generate the `chapters` array. You could always add a condition in the outer query that filters out rows where the chapters array is empty, but that would just be a workaround.

I think that you would better turn the inline query to a `join` with an aggregate query that generates the array of chapters of each book. The `join` eliminates books without chapters.

Here is an updated version of your query (I used json_build_object()`rather than`row_to_json()` to limit the nesting:

```
select 
    json_build_object(
        'book_id', b.book_id, 
        'book_title', b.book_title, 
        'chapters', c.chapters
    ) res
from books b
inner join (
    select 
        book_id, 
        json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                'chapter_id', chapter_id, 
                'chapter_title', chapter_title, 
                'chapter_number', chapter_number
            ) 
            order by chapter_number
        ) chapters
        from chapters
        group by book_id
) c on c.book_id = c.book_id
```